# Postfix and Amazon S3

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, postfix-mta

I have a Postfix mail server running on a Amazon instance. Is there a way to interact with Postfix and save every mail that comes to server in a file on Amazon S3 and to save email details in a Amazon SQS queue (mail details: to, from, subject, etc, and Amazon S3 file name)?
I'm new in Linux and Postfix. Maybe a script or something?

Thank you.